# Generating a nice list with expl3

Tags: luatex, expl3

I'm trying to generate a list like `-1, -2` using expl3 and TL 2020. The idea is to transform every entry in the list and get nice list separators without a trailing separator.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\generateList}{m}
{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_mylist {#1}
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \str_clear_new:N \l_tmpa_str

  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_mylist {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {\clist_item:Nn \l_mylist \l_tmpa_int}

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int } < { \clist_count:N \l_mylist }
    {-\str_use:N \l_tmpa_str,~ }
    {\str_use:N \l_tmpa_str}
    }
}

\clist_new:N \l_mylist

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\generateList{1, 2}

\end{document}
```

but that does not work as I get

```
-\clist_item:Nn \l_mylist \l_tmpa_int , \clist_item:Nn \l_mylist \l_tmpa_int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\clist_item:Nn` before setting the string, so use `\str_set:Nx` instead of `\str_set:Nn` (the `x` in `Nx` means “exhaustive expansion”):

```latex
    %  expand V
    \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \clist_item:Nn \l_mylist \l_tmpa_int }
```

However `expl3` provides you with tools to use a list with a separator.  You can use

```latex
\clist_use:Nn <clist-var> { <separator> }
```

But since you want to modify the items in the list (to add the `-`), then it's easier to turn everything into a `seq` variable:

```latex
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_mylist_seq {#1}
```

then add the `-` to all items:

```
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l_mylist_seq \l_mylist_seq { -##1 }
```

and then use the sequence with `,~` as separator:

```
    \seq_use:Nn \l_mylist_seq { ,~ }
```

and it will print:

> [image]

Here's the full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_mylist_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\generateList}{m}
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_mylist_seq {#1}
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l_mylist_seq \l_mylist_seq { -##1 }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_mylist_seq { ,~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\generateList{1, 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'll use your seq solution as it is much more readable.